# How to handle gosec linter warning: Potential file inclusion via variable

Tags: go

How do I solve the following warning from [gosec](https://github.com/securego/gosec) linter:

```
::warning: Potential file inclusion via variable,MEDIUM,HIGH (gosec)
```

The linter is warning me on the first line of this function:

```
func File2lines(filePath string) ([]string, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(filePath) //Warning here
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    return linesFromReader(f)
}
```

I have tried reading up on local file inclusion, but cannot see how that would be applicable here.

Comment: you are trying to open a file through a variable which can be dynamic, i.e., if user of your application is providing the `filePath`, then you can possibly be affected if you are executing some scripts from mentioned file, if you are just reading from file, then you can ignore the warning,in-order to get rid of the warning hard-code the path.

Comment: Reading from arbitrary files can also be dangerous - exposing data, read triggering bugs etc.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Where does the path come from? If you’re not absolutely sure it can never have user input, best to clean it before use and use a known prefix, e.g.:

```
filePath = filepath.Join(basePath,filepath.Clean(filePath))
f, err := os.Open(filePath)
```

That should fix the complaint. This is a reasonable precaution anyway even if you think it is safe now, in case later someone uses your function with user data.

Comment: `gosec` complains about the path not being clean when passed to `os.Open()`. More than likely, the ordering of the calls here needs to be changed since the initial use of `basePath` could still be a security issue. 

Consider instead: `filepath.Clean(filepath.Join(basePath, filePath))`.

Comment: It depends if basePath is a constant defined at compile time - if so it is safe but gosec may not be clever enough to recognise that. You could wrap it all in clean path agato be sure as well, but clean should be used on the path which is user provided.

Answer (score 10):

If you specify the file path with a variable, there is a risk that an unintended file path will be specified. Therefore, you should use `filepath.Clean()` to clean up possible bad paths.

an easy solution:

```golang
f,err := os.Open(filepath.Clean(fname))
```

Comment: @Dropout explanation added

Answer (score 8):

No one said the linter was *smart*. Looking at the function in isolation, it's impossible to say if there's a security issue. If the function is called with a `filePath` that's user-supplied and insufficiently validated, *and* it runs in a context where it can read files that the user would not be able to otherwise (e.g. in a program with elevated privileges, or on a remote server), *then* there is a probably issue. Otherwise, the only thing to do about the warning is to suppress or ignore it.